# printing a number pattern in python without white space and new line at the end

Tags: python, python-3.x

The aim is to print a pattern half triangle depending upon the user input for example if the user input is 3 the pattern would be

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
```

but upon executing there is a space after the each element of the last column and a new line (\n) after the last row. i would like to remove that please help.

```
1 \n
1 2 \n
1 2 3 \n
```

likewise whereas the expected output is

```
1\n
1 2\n
1 2 3
```

here is the code i wrote

```
rows = int(input())
num = 1
for i in range (0, rows):
  num = 1
  for j in range(0, i + 1):
    print(num,end=" ")
    num = num + 1
  print("")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Others have already shown the alternatives. Anyway, I believe that you are learning, and you want to understand that exact case. So, here is my comment.

YOU print the space. You cannot unprint it when already printed. There are more ways to solve that. If you want to preserve the spirit of your solution, you must not print the space after the last `num`. You can do one less turn of the inner loop, and print the last num separately, like this:

```
rows = int(input())
num = 1
for i in range (0, rows):
    num = 1
    for j in range(0, i):
        print(num, end=' ')
        num = num + 1
    print(num)
```

In the example, the first `num` line can be removed. Also, you combine *counted loop* with your own counting (the `num`). It usually means it can be simplified. Like this:

```
rows = int(input('Type the number of rows: '))
for i in range (0, rows):
    for j in range(1, i + 1):
        print(j, end=' ')
    print(i + 1)
```

Now, some experiment. Everything under the outer loop is actually printing a row of numbers. The sequence is generated by the `range` -- the generator that produces the sequence. When the sequence is wrapped by `list()`, you get a list of the numbers, and you can print its representation:

```
rows = int(input('Type the number of rows: '))
for i in range (1, rows + 1):
    print(list(range(1, i + 1)))
```

It prints the result like...

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Instead, you want to print the sequences of the same numbers joined by space. For that purpose, you can use `join`. However, you have to convert each of the elements to a string:

```
rows = int(input('Type the number of rows: '))
for i in range (1, rows + 1):
    print(' '.join(str(e) for e in range(1, i + 1)))
```

And that is already similar to the solutions presented by others. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Its too simple than the code you have made:

```
a = int(input("Enter a num: "))

for i in range(a+1):
    print(" ".join(list(map(str,range(1,i+1)))),end="")
    if i != a:print("")
```

Executing:

```
Enter a num: 3

1
1 2
1 2 3
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following soltuion, building the whole result string first before printing it without new line character at the end:

```
my_input = int(input("Enter a num: "))

s = ""
for i in range(my_input):
    s += " ".join([str(j) for j in range(1,i+2)])
    s += "\n" if i != my_input-1 else ""

print(s, end="")
```

Answer (score 0):

My version of your requirement,

```
rows = int(input('Enter a number - '))
num = 1
for i in range(0, rows):
    num = 1
    tmp = []
    for j in range(0, i + 1):
        tmp.append(str(num))
        num = num + 1
    if i + 1 == rows:
        print(repr("{}".format(' '.join(tmp))))
    else:
        print(repr("{}\n".format(' '.join(tmp))))
```

p.s - Remove `repr()` if not required

Output

```
Enter a number - 3
'1\n'
'1 2\n'
'1 2 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing a line piece by piece, or building a string by repetitively adding to it, the usual and efficient way in Python is to put all the values you want to print in a list, then to use `join` to join them.

Also, you don't need two imbricated loops: just append the latest number to your existing list on each loop, like this:

```
rows = int(input())
values = []

for i in range(1, rows + 1):
    values.append(str(i))
    print(' '.join(values))
```

Output:

```
3
1
1 2
1 2 3
```